# Fragment backstack with children fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, back-stack

I have my app that has a Main activity with a drawer. Every item on the drawer sends me to a fragment.

When I press the back button from those fragments, I want to be taken to the Main activity.

The problem is that I have a child fragment in one of my fragments. I want the back button in the child to take me to the parent fragment.

Actually I need the same thing with different parents.

How do I do that?

Here is my `MainActivity`:

```
package com.example.matancohen.sg50;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    displayView(R.id.nav_home);



}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}

private void displayView(int itemId) {
    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (itemId) {
        case R.id.nav_home:
            fragment = new Article();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_Recipes:
            fragment = new RecipesMain();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_Converter:
            fragment = new Converter();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_Videos:
            fragment = new Videos();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_Tracking:
            fragment = new Tracking();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_TrainerMenu:
            fragment = new TrainerMenu();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_Settings:
            fragment = new Settings();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_About:
            showDialog();
            break;

    }


    if (fragment != null) {
        final Fragment finalFragment = fragment;
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out)
                        .replace(R.id.content_main, finalFragment)
                        .commit();
            }
        }, 0);
            }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }




@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    displayView(item.getItemId());
    return true;
}
}
```

Recipe fragment:

```
package com.example.matancohen.sg50;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;


public class RecipesMain extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recipes,container,false);
}
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
    getActivity().setTitle("מתכונים");
    ImageButton stuffedBreast = (ImageButton)getView().findViewById(R.id.stuffedbreast);
    stuffedBreast.setOnClickListener(this);
    ImageButton breastSweetpotato = (ImageButton)getView().findViewById(R.id.chickensweetpotato);
    breastSweetpotato.setOnClickListener(this);
    ImageButton Cabbage = (ImageButton)getView().findViewById(R.id.cabbage);
    Cabbage.setOnClickListener(this);
    ImageButton chickenMeatballs = (ImageButton)getView().findViewById(R.id.chickenmeatballs);
    chickenMeatballs.setOnClickListener(this);
    ImageButton Sushi = (ImageButton)getView().findViewById(R.id.sushi);
    Sushi.setOnClickListener(this);
    ImageButton SintaBalls = (ImageButton)getView().findViewById(R.id.sintaballs);
    SintaBalls.setOnClickListener(this);
    ImageButton Maakuda = (ImageButton)getView().findViewById(R.id.maakuda);
    Maakuda.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Fragment fragment = null;


    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.chickenmeatballs:
            fragment = new RecipeChickenMeatballs();
            break;

        case R.id.chickensweetpotato:
            fragment = new RecipeChickenSweetPotato();
            break;

        case R.id.cabbage:
            fragment = new RecipeCabbage();
            break;

        case R.id.stuffedbreast:
            fragment = new RecipeStuffedBreast();
            break;

        case R.id.sushi:
            fragment = new RecipeSushi();
            break;

        case R.id.sintaballs:
            fragment = new RecipeSintaballs();
            break;

        case R.id.maakuda:
            fragment = new RecipeMaakuda();
            break;
    }
    if (fragment != null){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.bottomtop, R.anim.topbottom,R.anim.popbottomtop,R.anim.poptopbottom);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it all, now your app when you press back from your child fragment (the one inside one of your drawer fragments) navigates to your main activity? or that's what you want to accomplish ?

Comment: please make the question clear

Comment: when I choose one of the child fragments in Recipe fragment its Just fine! i Go back to the Recipe Fragemnt.
but !
When I'm navigating from the navigation drawer to one of the fragment (you can see it in displayView method ) when I press back button it throw me out of the app.
how do I make it go to the Main activity?

Comment: @MatanCohen Did you try my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is override onBackPressed() method in MainActivity and write this code,

```
    @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return;
             }

            if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container) instanceof Article) {
                ((Article) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container)).handleOnBackPress();
                return;
            }

            if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
                displayView(R.id.nav_home);
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();

            }
        }
```

and add a new method in your Article fragment called handleOnBackPress() and write custom code for handling the back button .

Example :

```
public void handleOnBackPress() {
        System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Works like charm!
Can you explain this to me?

Comment: @Matan Cohen the logic is very simple , if the user is staying in the Article fragment we will handle the back button press in the Article fragment. The second condition check for the backstack count (scenario described in your question like RecipeMain fragment and the dril down fragment child fragment). If the count is zero we will go to the Article fragment else call super method.Please accept the answer if it is working for you.